# Manually setting top and left position of startup is not working

Tags: vb.net, registry

in the load event, I'm setting left and top position. What's happening is the form shows up in the default position, then goes to the location that I set manually. So it flashes at one position then immediately goes to the manual settings. (hope this makes sense.. let me know if I need to provide more info)

```
        Dim rkCurrentUser As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser

    If rkCurrentUser IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim rkTest As RegistryKey = rkCurrentUser.OpenSubKey("My Secret Life")

        If rkTest IsNot Nothing Then

            regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("My Secret Life")

            Dim myLeft As Integer = 0
            myLeft = regKey.GetValue("frmMainLeft", myLeft)

            Dim myTop As Integer = 0
            myTop = regKey.GetValue("frmMainTop", myTop)

            Dim myMinutes As Integer = 0
            myMinutes = regKey.GetValue("waitMinutes", myMinutes)

            Me.Top = myTop
            Me.Left = myLeft

            regKey.Close()
            rkTest.Close()
            rkCurrentUser.Close()

        End If


    Else
        MsgBox("Key doesn't exist")
        regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("My Secret Life")
        regKey.SetValue("waitMinutes", 0)
        regKey.SetValue("frmMainLeft", Me.Left)
        regKey.SetValue("frmMainTop", Me.Top)

        regKey.Close()

    End If

    rkCurrentUser.Close(
```

Thanks for any help... plus I know the last character is removed.

Comment: What is your `StartPosition` set to?

Comment: Does it also flicker when you remeove the registry loading stuff and set Top,Left to any value?

Comment: I guess that your form will always flash between locations. If you want it to start at a certain location, you'll need edit     StartPosition property. Otherwise you can set it's visibility to FALSE and turn it programmatically to TRUE when all the FormLoad is over.

Comment: ok... I'll check these out and let you know

Comment: sorry to take so long.. I inherited this project from someone else so the code is new to me. Form1 is not the startup page and a skinned window comes up. When I change the visible property to false, it does really weird things visually and loses it's skin.

Comment: Try setting the position before opening the form, instead of waiting for the opening event.

Comment: @peterG Thanks for the idea. I have it working now. It still flickers when it comes up, but at least it only shows up in one position. I'm not sure if what I did makes sense, but I changed the resize event to call form_load. That's what made things work. I would like to mark your answer as solved, but can't because I think you have to put your comments in an answer window? Not sure... still new at this. But thanks a lot!

Comment: So do you then re-call form_load on each resize?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer The resize event only occurs once because the the form cannot be resized.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that illustrates the kind of thing I usually do:

```
  Function Display() As DialogResult
    Me.Icon = frmMain.Icon 'so we only change icons in one place
    'other initialisation stuff goes here
    RestoreFormSettings(Me) 'get form position (and size if resizable) from registry (your code)
    Return Me.ShowDialog() 'show the form modally, then return dialog result
End Function
```

You should find that this gets rid of the flicker. I've also included what I do to ensure icon consistency across the app, and how to return a DialogResult which is one way for the calling code to know what you did in the form. To clarify, call this instead of calling frm.ShowDialog directly.